# How to recover text typed into a text box on chrome after the browser refreshed and cleared all information (mac)?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, dump, pid, macos-ventura

I had a job application completely typed out after hours of hard work, and used the website's 'save' feature - however to my despair the website randomly refreshed and I lost all my answers!

I've been following these steps posted on a much older question:[How do I recover information I've typed into a website after I accidentally lost the information?](https://superuser.com/questions/975744/how-do-i-recover-information-ive-typed-into-a-website-after-i-accidentally-lost?fbclid=IwAR0Kz-1CRZGv1QMXAEXuc-XBZ723PhZaBrMSKMTo0ohsSDOU5kVuV60vsIo)

However have got stuck trying to download a core dump - Terminal no longer seemes to recognise 'gcore', however I installed it from this link: https://web.archive.org/web/20200103164014/https://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter8/core/ and despite locating the required PID, when I request the core dump I get this message back: gcore: task_read_for_pid: (null)

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I'm pretty ignorant with these things but it would save me so much heartache to recover my answers!

Thank you